# Handle two kinds of request body in controller - java

Tags: java, api, rest, post, controller

I have a request body like this for post method.

```
{
"emp_id" : "1234"
}
```

Controller is like this.

```
@PostMapping("/employees)
public ResponseEntity<EmployeeResponse> getMatchingValues(@RequestBody HashMap<String,String> params){
}
```

Now my request body will be updated to the one as shown below.

```
{
"emp_id" : "1234",
"ids" : ["4567","9087"]
}
```

How can I update the post mapping in controller?
Can someone help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier to handle if you use a POJO to get the values from the request body

```
public RequestData{
  private String emp_id;
  private List<String> ids;
...
//TODO: getters and setters here
}
```

And then in the controller:

```
@PostMapping("/employees)
public ResponseEntity<EmployeeResponse> getMatchingValues(@RequestBody RequestData requestData){
}
```

This way, if a field is not included in the request, it will map it to null.

Answer (score 0):

You can consume the params in Map<String, Object>

> Below is the sample result.

```
@PostMapping("/employees)
public ResponseEntity<EmployeeResponse> getMatchingValues(@RequestBody HashMap<String,Object> params){
            System.out.println("params = "+params);
  
}
```

> Output is :
> params = {emp_id=1234, ids=[4567, 9087]}

Comment: The answers is the same as the question.